# How do I arrange columns with django_tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I know that I can change the order of attributes in my model class definition to change the order of (non-excluded) table columns.  Specifically, how do I insert a TemplateColumn in the second column instead of in the last column?  My read through the documentation shows every instance of 'sort' and of 'order' that I could find seems to apply to the rows of the table, not the columns.

Here's what I have:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
class EntryTable(tables.Table):
    concept = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='simplelist/entry_detail_link.html')
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ('id','list',)
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

and that template is really just the text of the record and the link to the detail page:

```
<a href="{% url 'simplelist:entry_detail' record.pk %}">{{record.concept_name}}</a>
```

And of course I needed a view and a template to display the table, but I got that working by pretty much following the docs so I'll spare you that unless it's needed.  This seems basic so I cannot believe I'm not finding it, but perhaps I'm tripping over all the information on how to sort/order the *rows* of the table.   ...but my vision is blurring, so perhaps I'm overdue for sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `sequence`:

```
class EntryTable(tables.Table):
    concept = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='simplelist/entry_detail_link.html')

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ('id','list',)
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        sequence = ("entry_field_1", "concept", "...")
```

[Docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#swapping-the-position-of-columns)

Comment: Thanks!  If not so tired, I probably could have found it by just reading the entire page - I guess the words I did not search for were 'swap' and 'position' or I would have found it: [swapping-the-position-of-columns](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#swapping-the-position-of-columns)